# jsonp Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

i want see some game info on steam. I find a api, but when i use it say:

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Also, I use json**p** but it is throw an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

My code is below:

```
$.ajax({
    //crossDomain: 'true',
    url: 'http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=730',
    //url: 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/',
    //url:'http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=730',
    //url:'games.json',
    type: 'get',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    //dataType:'json',
    //data = JSON.parse(data);
    crossDomain : true,
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(data){
        console.log("Hata ",data);
    }
});
```

I use anyorigin.com but it is not work. When I use local .json file working, but I need steam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the URL you have in your example supports JSONP. I see this sort of JSON response:

```
{
  "key": "value"
}
```

And for JSONP it needs to be:

```
callback({ key: value })
```

There might be some confusion here about what JSONP is. JSONP requires the API serve up raw javascript. Not only that, the server must serve up a *particular* function call in that javascript. JSONP is a hack around cross-origin policies.

edit:
As for solution, I would suggest you proxy the JSON through your own server-side application.